AWS CodePipeline Deploy stage Can't Access Dockerfile During Deploy Stage
During the Deploy stage in AWS CodePipeline I receive the following error:
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to read Dockerfile: open /var/app/staging/server/backend.Dockerfile: no such file or directory
However, when I deploy my image via eb deploy CMD, it works without problems.
Also, locally the images build successfully.
I followed this tutorial https://bentranz.medium.com/setup-continuous-deployment-pipeline-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk-5f8edb38d872
Here's my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: ***********.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/some-repo:latest
    container_name: servername
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RDS_USER=${RDS_USER}
      - RDS_PASSWORD=${RDS_PASSWORD}
      - RDS_SERVER=${RDS_SERVER}
      - RDS_PORT=${RDS_PORT}
      - RDS_DB=${RDS_DB}
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS=${SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS}
      - SENDGRID_API_KEY=${SENDGRID_API_KEY}    
      - AWS_KEY_ID=${AWS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
    build: 
        context: ./server
        dockerfile: backend.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server/app/:/app/
      - public_assets:/app/shared/public
    # env_file:
    #   - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - howdynetwork
    # depends_on:
    #   - database
    #   - cache

And here's my buildspec.yml
version: 0.2

phases:
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - echo "Logging in to Amazon ECR..."
            - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
            - COMMIT_SHA=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
            - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_SHA:-latest}
    build:
        commands:
            - echo "Build started on `date`"
            - docker build -f ./server/backend.Dockerfile -t $IMAGE_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG ./server
            - docker tag $IMAGE_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
            # - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
            - echo "Build completed on `date`"
    post_build:
        commands:
            - echo "Push the docker image to AWS ECR..."
            - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
            - echo "Update IMAGE_TAG in docker-compose.yml..."
            - sed -i -e "s/\${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}/$IMAGE_TAG/g" docker-compose.yml
artifacts:
    files:
        - .ebextensions/**/*
        - docker-compose.yml
        - nginx.conf

I tried to switch configure CodeBuild platoform for both Ubuntu and Amazon Linux 2. Also, tried the eb deploy cmd.

Are you supposed to have a backend.Dockerfile at /var/app/staging/server/, or should it be one level above at /var/app/staging/?. Log into your EC2 instance to determine the location of backend.Dockerfile.

If anyone is interested, the issue was resolved on AWS re:Post
enter link description here

Links go stale. You should post a summary of the issue was resolved.
